# Redirecting my Heroku app to a custom domain on BigRock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I have added my domain to heroku using `heroku domains:add`.

Now when I run `heroku domains` in my terminal, I get

```
=== sampleapp Domain Names
sampleapp.herokuapp.com
sampleapp.me
www.sampleapp.me
```

I'm unable to configure BigRock's DNS to point to the Heroku-supplied DNS Target (which is `sampleapp.herokuapp.com`).

There's a domain forwarding option in BigRock, but when I use it, it shows my Heroku app in an `iframe`.

In the DNS management panel, I see `A records`, `CNAME records` etc., but I have no understanding of what they mean. I have, however, added a `www` cname with the value shown in the image below.

[image: bigrock dns management panel]

Can someone please tell me how I should go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: That `CNAME` setting looks OK. Can you share the real domain name?

Comment: thanks @DusanBajic. It is now working with "www" in front of it. I just read more about it and it seems that the naked domain isn't working. Just pointed it to wwwizer's IP, should see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my A records for WWW to get it working. 
For naked domain, CNAME is not recommended.